# Replacing values in a comma-separated list in DataStage / DB2

Tags: db2, datastage

A new reporting requirement has arisen and I'm not too sure of the best way to tackle it. The source system has a field in it - let's call the field 'Fruit codes'. The Fruit codes field contains a list of comma-separated fruits. These are stored as semi-meaningful values Eg.

```
ID    -    Fruit codes 
100   -    APL, BAN, STRW 
101   -    ORNG 
102   -    BAN, STRW
```

There is a table that maps these semi-meaningful values to the full string equivalent. Eg.

```
Fruit code - Fruit name 
APL        -  Apple 
BAN        -  Banana 
STRW       -  Strawberry
ORNG       -  Orange
```

We want to be able to display the full-string equivalent, separated by commas. The expected output should look like this:

```
ID    -    Fruit names 
100   -    Apple, Banana, Strawberry 
101   -    Orange 
102   -    Banana, Strawberry
```

We are using DataStage 9.1 with DB2 9.7. I was hoping that I might be able to use the `Ereplace function` in DataStage, however I'm not sure that this will work. The list of possible Fruits changes every now and then, so I want this to be dynamic. I wonder whether I might need to loop through each of the comma-separated list of fruits and then somehow to an Ereplace using the mapping table. Perhaps I will need to separate the comma-separated lists into individual rows or columns.

Maybe it's possible to do this using the Pivot stage, or the opposite of the `LISTAGG DB2` function (if this exists). I'm not so proficient in DataStage, so I have lots of ideas, but no answers!

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It would be best to fix your data to be more normalized, which would turn this into a set of simple joins.  Querying and updating data stored this way is a **nightmare**.  This is technically a type of un-pivot operation, but you're generally not supposed to need to do it, because your data would have to be in the wrong form.  I've split strings into rows via a recusive CTE before, and you could potentially create a function do something related.  But your best bet is to store the data correctly (as a cross-ref table).

Comment: Hi Clockwork, thanks for your reply. I've been away on vacation so only just saw your response. Unfortunately I don't have any control over the source data (I'm just a user). I agree, this is very nightmarish. I'll take a look into your suggestion of un-pivoting the data.

Comment: The wacky thing is that doing it this way makes everybody's lives difficult.  I'd get it a bit more if you were storing the actual _names_, but storing the codes just makes it hard on the actual programmers, too.  Are you possibly looking at a view that's doing this in the first place?  If you have a normalized set of tables, you can get this trivially (via `LISTAGG(...)`, natch).  Migrating to a proper form could use views to dummy out the tables, although you'd need instead-of triggers.  Otherwise, best bet is a function that returns a table.